# Custom name domain with github page and jekyll

Tags: github, static, jekyll, github-pages, ovh

I'm trying to setup a custom domain name on my jekyll project. Here is my configuration :

**----------------------**

[gh-pages configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZmIm.png)

[CNAME content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq0vY.png)

[OVH dns configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6gt3.png)

Branch : gh-pages

CNAME : adrienmerre.fr

Enforce HTTPS : No ( for the moment )

DNS configuration : i've made four "A" with github ip (185.199.1xx.153), and a CNAME at www.adrienmerre.fr. for amerre.github.io

**----------------------**

My homepage is loading, but no css, and all the content is not displaying (without custom domain name it's working perfectly)( 404 on each pages ). I don't get it, i've been looking for github doc, jekyll doc, topics on stack overflow, tutorials... If someone can explain to me what i'm doing wrong, that would be awesome !

Here's the project repo if you wan't to see more : https://github.com/amerre/adr_blog

Thanks !

Comment: Please post the relevant code/configuration to answer the question here without need to leave the site

Comment: Maybe the old DNS settings have not yet expired?

Comment: It seems to be working fine: https://adrienmerre.fr. I use this setup all the time. Can you give a little bit more datail on the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had the same issue when trying to run Jekyll on Github. I dug around, trying to look for an answer, but with no luck.

I ended up using [www.netlify.com](http://netlify.com), as they have Jekyll support, and continuous deployment, just like Github. I'd recommend giving it a try, and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Running a website with a custom domain name on github pages is as basic as it gets. It is free and it should work. Giving up and referring somebody to a paid service does not really seem like a valid solution to me.

Comment: It's now working, i've just hosted it on netlify. I'll stay with it, but you'r right. I will restart the configuration with github pages in few weeks when i will had more time.